# Is there any way to disable clickable landmarks on Google Maps API if I'm using vue2-google-maps package?

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, vuejs2, vue2-google-maps

I am trying to remove the clickable landmarks on the Google Maps API and I have found the property which I must set to false if I want to do that, however, since I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps, I can't seem to figure out how to do that, and the vue2-google-maps documentation doesn't seem to indicate how to change this property.

Based on this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.clickableIcons , I need to set `clickableIcons` to false. Sadly I can't figure out how to access that property `clickableIcons`.

So far I've accessed a couple of other properties like zoom and center this way:

```
        <GmapMap ref="mapRef"
            @click='createMarker'
            :center="center"
            :zoom="zoom"
            :map-type-id="map"
            style="width: 100%; height: 800px"
        >
        </GmapMap>
```

However, adding :clickableIcons: false seem to not do anything in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You could consider the following options to set *map icons as not clickable*

**Option 1**

[`google.maps.MapOptions.clickableIcons` property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.clickableIcons) in `vue-google-maps` could be set like this:

```
<GmapMap :center="center" :zoom="zoom" :options="options"></GmapMap>


export default {
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 12,
      center: { lat: 51.5287718, lng: -0.2416804 },
      options: {
        clickableIcons: false
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**Option 2**

By access to [`google.maps.Map.setClickableIcons` method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setClickableIcons) via `ref`:

```
<GmapMap :center="center" :zoom="zoom" ref="mapRef"></GmapMap>


export default {
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 12,
      center: { lat: 51.5287718, lng: -0.2416804 },
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
     this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then(() => {
        this.$refs.mapRef.$mapObject.setClickableIcons(false)
    })
  }
}
```